# Infobubble Keep Adding tab and Not removing the previous tab added

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]I encountered this problem and I'm new on using Infobubble for Google Maps and when i click the marker and add tab, when i change the marker clicked the Previous tab  still show
all i want is to remove the previous tab.

This is my Snippet:

```
 function codeAddress() {
        infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            shadowStyle: 0,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
            arrowSize: 15,
            maxWidth: 300,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            arrowPosition: 30,
            arrowStyle: 0
        });
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                var Name = this["Name"];
                var Gender = this["Gender"];
                var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal

                        })

                        $('#places').append($('<li>')
                                    .text(currVal)
                                    .data('location', results[0].geometry.location));

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                            $('#places li').css('display', function () {
                                return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                            });
                        });

                        //mgr = new MarkerManager(map);


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infoBubble.addTab(Name, Name + "" + currVal + "" + Gender + "" + Bdate);
                                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);

                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
        });
    }
```

As you can see. the tab for Britney Spears is there on the marker of Miley Cyrus.
All i want is to remove the first clicked marker tab

Comment: it looks like you're adding tabs to one infowindow and changing the latlong co-ordinates of it each time a different marker is clicked. but it seems like you want to show only one infowindow per marker and not an infowindow with multiple tabs.
where's your declaration of `infoBubble`?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something like this instead of adding tabs to one infowindow and changing it's location each time?

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latValue, longValue);
var mapOptions = {
  ...
  center: myLatlng
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var infoBubble = null;

...

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (infoBubble) {
        infoBubble.close();
    }
    infoBubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: singersTextContent});
    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
    ...
});
```

Comment: the problem is that when i click the marker again, the Infobubble doubles and continues to add the same tab. how should i fix it?

Comment: wow! okay, that will need some more research, I haven't worked with gmaps in a while